# Outputting ASCII in Hex form?

Tags: c++, hex, output, ascii, aes

I'm trying to implement AES for a school project. My goal is to output the encrypted text to both the screen and a .txt file. The encryption goes totally as expected, and I can verify this by looking at this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j<object.words * 4; j++)
    {
        printf("%02x ", Encryptor.out[j]);
    }
```

The text it is encrypting is "im so glad this works", with the 128-bit key 'dog', and this loop prints the first 16 characters of the encryption, which reads:

```
c8 88 45 0d 5d 40 ff 5b a4 55 91 c9 c4 00 f5 a4
```

I've verified that this is what AES should print in this context. Later, I have the following lines of output:

```
this is Encryptor.out[0] in cout: ╚
This is Encryptor.out[0] in printf with the format code '%02x': c8
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My cout call probably just needs a formatting code, so I'm not concerned about that. The complication is at this point:

```
ofstream OutFile("Encrypted.txt");
Outfile << Encryptor.out[0];
```

At this point, the only thing contained within Encrypted.txt is the single character 'È'. I know that c8 in hex is 'È' in ASCII, but I want it to print the original hex value.

So ultimately, my question is, how do I get this character to be saved in my output file as 'c8'? Is there a formatting code that ofstream can use, or do I have to jump through some hoops?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried converting the array to unicode or any of the UTF formats?

Comment: The `<<` operator for char data will output the ASCII character.  Add the `std::hex` operator to output it as a hex value.

Comment: `std::cout << std::hex << whatever;` .

Answer (score 2):

Like @stark commented, to print data in hex you can use `std::hex` which modifies the way your data is formatted. However, `std::hex` only changes the way that numbers are printed so you need to tell the compiler to treat your text as numbers. Fortunately there's an easy way to do this. You can use

```
ofstream OutFile("Encrypted.txt");
OutFile << std::hex;
for (const char c : Encryptor.out[0])
{
    OutFile << static_cast<int>(c);
}
// Reset back to normal printing
OutFile << std::dec;
```

and you will get the correct hex value and not the accented character E.

Check out `std::hex` here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Comment: I wrote "OutFile << std::hex <<Encryptor.out[0];", just like you suggested, but it still saves the character as È. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What's the type of `Encryptor.out[0]`? If it's `std::string` try using `OutFile << std::hex << Encryptor.out[0].c_str();`

Comment: @JamesJuchau updating my answer now with something that I have tested

Comment: Your latest edit worked! I wouldn't have thought to cast it as an integer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JamesJuchau that's c++ wonkiness for ya!